# Is there a way in html or JS so that when I hover over something it changes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

More specifically, when I hover my cursor over a picture it would transform into a different picture. Or what I'm actually looking for: When I hover over text it would change into different text.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can do this with JavaScript.  Can you be more specific as to what you want to do?  First you need to catch the mouseover event.  Next you need to manipulate the DOM.  I suggest looking into jQuery to make this easy, but it isn't 100% necessary.

Comment: Please go to “help”, “Tour”.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you would use the DOM events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. to change the image source.

Or you could use CSS `:hover` psuedo-class like this:

```
<div class="derp"></div>

.derp {
    background-image:url(someURL);
}
.derp:hover {
    background-image:url(someOtherURL);
}
```

Comment: −1. Events are not language-specific (the entire DOM API is not), and they are `mouseover` and `mouseout`; anything else is proprietary at this time.  And an element with no content has no intrinsic `width` or `height`, therefore no visible `background-image`.

Comment: mouseout is different than mouseleave. mouseout also fires if you mouse off a child of the listener. There is nothing wrong with calling those events @PointedEars.

Comment: That an this isn't a copy-paste-problem-solved-answer. It's a guide to right right way of learning.

Comment: @rlemon First of all, events are not called; at most they are *fired at* elements and *handled* by listeners. Second, there is no child element, so bubbling is not an issue (or maybe there is a child and bubbling is wanted – who knows?). Third, you should not rely on events that are only in a [Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/) when there are sufficiently equivalent events in a [Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's easiest with the CSS `:hover` pseudo-elector.

```
#theimage {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: url('image1.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}

#theimage:hover {
  background: url('image2.png') 0 0 no-repeat
}
```

If you want to do things that are more complicated then you can use Javascript, which can use more complicated logic and access properties and attributes like the `src` of an image tag.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wev64/)

You would also probably want to preload the image so that there is no delay the first time you hover (after clearing your cache). That's done best with Javascript:

```
<script>
  (new Image).src = 'image2.png';
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

For changing text, you'll probably want to use JS. You could do something like this:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    function changetext()
    {
        var textchange2 = "new text" ;
        var id = document.getElementById("ElementToChange");
        id.innerHTML=textchange2;
    }

    function changetextback()
    {
        var textchange2 = "original text" ;
        var id = document.getElementById("ElementToChange");
        id.innerHTML=textchange2;
    }
</script>
<div id="ElementToChange" onmouseover="changetext();" onmouseout="changetextback();">original text</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, that is a standard function of Javascript to handle HTML DOM events. Using simple HTML/Javascript, you can attach an onmouseover event handler to run a Javascript function:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function changeText(obj){
            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent
            obj.textContent = "some new text";

            // you could also use obj.innerHTML here, but 
            // that comes with security considerations
            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv" onmouseover="changeText(this)">Some text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

There are convenience functions in Javascript frameworks like jQuery as well:

```
$(obj).text('Some new text from jQuery');
```

Note that you need to include the jQuery library in your `<head>` block to use it.

Attaching event handlers to DOM events via inline properties like `onmouseover` may result in harder to manage code over the long run. Attaching event listeners via code is better:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function changeText(event){
            // the Event object - here called event as a variable name
            // is passed implicitly
                event.target.textContent = "some new text";
            }

            window.onload = function(){
                document.getElementById("mydiv")
                    .addEventListener("mouseover", changeText, false );
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">Some text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery makes it easy:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mydiv")
        .on( "mouseover", function(event){
            $(event.target).text('some new text');
    });
});
```

I suggest you Google Javascript tutorials and go through an HTML/Javascript beginner's tutorial. Mozilla Developer Network is a good place to start learning:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

If you really get interested in it, check out NodeJS for server-side Javascript:

http://nodejs.org/

Comment: w3schools isn't a great place for beginners. it is filled with bad practices, ill / incomplete advice and anti-patterns. I suggest MDN (which is a public wiki) as a better choice. w3schools might not be *that bad* for an experienced developer, but for a beginner it is bad news bears.

Comment: [Events are *not*, I repeat, *not* a feature of “Javascript” – they are of the DOM –, and there is no such programming language](http://PointedEars.de/es-matrix).

Comment: Did you just use yourself as a citation reference?

Comment: @RUJordan Yes, I did cite a decade of work on the subject, including the result of my thesis. You can follow the links therein, visit MDN or probably anything else !(w3schools || script_kiddie) if you do not believe me.

Comment: @rlemon, good point, I have updated the reference to MDN. Late afternoon sleepy-brain is to blame!

Comment: @RobertMunn it might also be worth noting that `event` as an argument name is misleading in this case, inline event listeners in HTML are hard(er) to maintain in the long run (same with inline styles) and innerHTML to replace text is not the right choice. *fyi*

Comment: @PointedEars, I changed my post to note that the onmouseover property points to an event handler. I appreciate your insistence on precision.

Comment: @rlemon, Yep, just changed that argument, I seem to be coming out of the post-lunch torpor now :). Since we're being precise, would you use obj.firstChild.nodeValue to change the text value?

Comment: @RobertMunn That would be unnecessary and not equivalent. `.innerHTML` is still proprietary but [a well-supported quasi-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) that suffices here. If it is only text content, you could use [`.textContent` (from DOM Level 3 Core)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) with reduced compatibility.

Comment: @PointedEars, I think `.textContent` is better in this case, as I was illustrating the replacement of plain text and `.innerHTML` can be exploited. Updating my answer ...